# get wsdl value from xml file

Tags: xml, wsdl

I have the following xml file:

```
<properties>
  <type>1</type> <!-- 1 or 2>

  <prop1> test </prop1>
  <prop2> test2 </prop2>
</properties>
```

and the wsdl file:

```
<definitions>
  <xmlProp>test</xmlProp>
</definitions>
```

I want wsdl tag "xmlProp" get value from xml tag's value prop1.
In addition i want to have an if statement in wsdl and if xml tag "type" is 1 the wsdl tag xmlProp get the prop1 value otherwise get prop2 value.

Is there any way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

I have an XSL approach that should work for you.

The XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="YourFile.xslt"?>

<properties>
  <type>1</type> <!-- 1 or 2>-->
  <prop1> test </prop1>
  <prop2> test2 </prop2>
</properties>
```

The XSLT file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:element name="definitions">
      <xsl:element name="xmlProp">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="/properties[type = 1]">
            <xsl:value-of select="/properties/prop1" />
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:value-of select="/properties/prop2" />
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:element>
    </xsl:element>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions>
  <xmlProp> test </xmlProp>
</definitions>
```

I hope this helps.